# Making an array from a plist issue

Tags: file-io, nsarray, plist, ios5

First, a little background. I am trying to make a platform game. In front of the game layer I want "lights" to go by and by lights I mean white triangles. I am trying to get coordinates for the triangles from a plist.

At this point I have spent days trying to get my app to read from a plist and I cannot get it to work.
This is what I currently have and this is basically what the internet is saying I should have and that it should work.

In helloWorld.h:

```
NSMutableArray *foregroundLights;
```

In helloWorld.m

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foregroundlights" ofType:@"plist"];
foregroundLights = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

I have tried formatting the patch every way that I can think of, I have tried using NSSearchPathsForDirectoriesInDomains. I have tried making the plist a dictionary and making it an array. What am I missing?

Here is a piece of the plist. The full one contains 50 arrays of 4 ints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>root</key>
<array>
    <array>
        <integer>128</integer>
        <integer>68</integer>
        <integer>246</integer>
        <integer>7</integer>
    </array>
    <array>
        <integer>181</integer>
        <integer>84</integer>
        <integer>170</integer>
        <integer>62</integer>
    </array>
    <array>
        <integer>118</integer>
        <integer>51</integer>
        <integer>142</integer>
        <integer>64</integer>
    </array>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Right now the plist is a dictionary with one key "root" so the NSMutableArray init will return nil.  Have you tried removing the `<dict>` and `<key>` nodes and having just the `<array>` in the plist?  When you run the code, does it give an error or is the array just nil?

Comment: Removing the `<dict>` and `<key>` worked so far, there are other bug that I need to get through. It is weird that Xcode added that initial dictionary to the plist.